# Inflate screen-specific layouts programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Is it possible to inflate `screen-specific` layouts programmatically?

I have 2 layouts for same screen one of them is `sw600dp`, for tablet landscape I want to use `sw600dp` but for tablet portrait I want to use default `layout`, because my screen splitted to 2 fragments.

Because the tablet is big, both landscape and portrait bigger then 600dp.

Comment: you can look at https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-determine-android-screen-size-dimensions-orientation/ on how to determine screen sizes programmatically.

Comment: I know the screen size, I looking how to inflate layout of specific layout directory sw600dp,sw320dp etc

Comment: and incase I misunderstand your question "layout-sw600dp-land" is also a valid choice (screen sizes with orientation)  that you can use to differentiate your layouts. see https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseOriQuali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the screen size, then you take the idea from the example in 'use layout aliases'
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes
(scroll to the part on "Use Layout aliases")

> To avoid this duplication of the same file, you can use alias files. For example, you can define the following layouts:

```
res/layout/main.xml            # single-pane layout
res/layout/main_twopanes.xml   # two-pane layout
```

basically, instead of putting them in different layout folders, just name them differently and put all the layouts in the default layout folder.

for your case, since you want to do it programmatically,
then just check if your screensize > xxx size, inflate the bigger layout.

so you may end up with files like the following

```
res/layout/main_sw320.xml   
res/layout/main.xml       
res/layout/main_sw600.xml
```

Comment: So as I understand there are no native way to do it, just to give different names?

Comment: @PavelPoley there is also a "hack" to detect the screen sizes by putting a view in the layout-sw600dp, but not in the default. then check if  findViewById for that view is null or not. (if it is not null then you have loaded sw600dp, otherwise, default is loaded) see http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-make-two-pane-layout-in-android/